# Error when adding google map to page

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add the google map with a marker into my form in order to help users choose the location, but it went wrong somewhere.

[image: Error when entering the form]

As you see, the map didn't display correctly in its area. I've put a marker into the map and also set center there, but the location of that marker is not correct, it hides outside the initial map (in the top right of the map above, instead of the center).

When I hit the F12 button to enable Firebug (in firefox), the map display correctly
[image: The map display correctly when enable firebug]

Here's the code for creating the form and adding google map:

The form in index.html file:

```
<div id="map_company" style="float: left; width: 500px;height: 350px;">
 <label style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Chọn vị trí hãng xe trên bản đồ:</label>
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;"></div>
</div>
```

And the javascript in the script file:

```
//add map to company tab
//Set Center 
var myOptions = 
{
center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.044813, 105.79864),
zoom: 13,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
}
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
  myOptions);
var comMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(21.044813, 105.79864),
    map: map,
draggable: true
});
google.maps.event.addListener(comMarker, 'dragend', function {
document.getElementById("cLat").value = this.getPosition().lat();
document.getElementById("cLon").value = this.getPosition().lng();
});
```

Can anyone help me to figure out the problem here, I even don't know how to explain it to google.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you use tabs.

When yes, you must trigger the resize-event of the map when the tab with the map has been selected.

Answer (score 0):

Give your map_canvas a fixed size (in pixels, not percentage) and remove the position = relative. If you use percentages the parent node must also have a size, otherwise it make no sense, (100% of what?).

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
```